# my HTML5 Code does not work

Tags: html, canvas

I have written the following HTML5 code with JavaScript which is exactly an example of HTML5 Canvas, but it doesn't work in my browsers.  I tried in Safari, Firefox, and Opera.  I looked for errors several time and corrected some small errors, but it doesn't work yet.

Please check it and let me know what the mistake can be.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src = "modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);
        var Debugger = function() {};
        Debugger.log = function(message){
            try{
                console.log(message);
            } catch (exception){
                return;
            }
        }
        function eventWindowLoaded(){
            canvasApp();
        }
        function canvasSupport(){
            return Modernizr.canvas;
        }
        function canvasApp(){
            if (!convasSupport()){
                return;
            }
            var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canone");
            var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d")

            Debugger.log("Nooooooooooooooooo");

            function drawScreen(){

                //background
                context.fillStyle="#ffffaa";
                context.fillRect=(0,0,500,500);

                //text
                context.fillStyle="#000000";
                context.font="20px_sans";
                context.textBaseline="top";
                context.fillText("hello world", 250, 100);

                //image
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = "lund.jpg";
                image.onload = function(){
                    context.drawImage(image, 160, 130);
                }

                //box
                context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                context.strokeRect(20, 50, 490, 290);
            }
        drawScreen();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:absolut;top:50px;left:50px;">
    <canvas id="canone" width ="500" height ="300">
        your browser does not support html5
    </canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be more specific about what's not working. Do you check the console for errors?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What errors do you get?

Comment: I am quit new in HTML and using Notpad++. I don not know how to debug my code in that.

Comment: You can't. If you want to debug web code, load it up in a browser. Notepad++ is a text editor, not a development environment. It happens to be a fairly good one that gives you code highlighting, but you still need to *run* your code once in a while to test it!

Comment: @General_Mayhem: what do you recomend me to use as an IDE which enables me to debug my code during the development?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Code needs to be run to be tested, particularly interpreted dynamic languages like JS because many more errors become runtime. There are many IDEs for frontend web development, but the easiest way to test is just to load it up in your browser, as that is Javascript's native runtime environment, just like you would compile and run a C program to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *did* test it, and misspelling `canvasSupport` is indeed the problem.

What exactly do you mean by "I looked for errors several times?" You need to be loading up your JavaScript error console (ctrl-shift-J on Chrome or Firefox) to see what gets printed there; functions not being defined (because you put the wrong name) is pretty easy to debug at that point.

Answer (score 2):

I did not test this, but I can see 1 mistake:

```
 if (!convasSupport()){
            return;
 }
```

There is not convasSupport function, should be canvasSupport()

Answer (score 1):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: convasSupport is not defined`

You need to open the developer window when debugging and look at the errors that are present.

You have a typo. It should be canvasSupport, not convasSupport.

Do a search for debugging JavaScript in your preferred browser. There are a lot of built in tools that will help you discover bugs like this instantly.